# Инструмент для автоматического выполнения действия

Tags: java, android

подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли в Java инструмент для выполнения простейшего действия с заданной периодичностью? Для примера: выполнять команду `x++` каждую секунду / каждые 5 с.

Можно было бы сделать простой цикл с задержкой и каким нибудь условием, но я не знаю, мб есть какой то инструмент специальный.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете использовать `Timer`:

```
int delay = 5000; // delay for 5 sec.
int period = 1000; // repeat every sec.
int count = 0;
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask()
    {
        public void run()
        {
           // Your code
            count++;
        }
    }, delay, period);
```